# SpssClient.RunSyntax result not available immediately

Tags: python, spss

In SPSS 23 I run some FREQUENCIES commands in a loop in a python program embedded in a SYNTAX file. After each command I want to access the resulting pivot table. This code is already heavily modified for debugging:

```py
SpssClient.RunSyntax( piechart_command.format( var ) )
OutputItemList = SpssOutput.GetOutputItems()
print "size " + str( OutputItemList.Size() )
print "iteration " + str(iteration)
statTables = []
for i in range( OutputItemList.Size() ):
    OutputItem = OutputItemList.GetItemAt( i )
    if OutputItem.GetType() == SpssClient.OutputItemType.PIVOT:
        statTables.append( OutputItem.GetSpecificType() )
print "length " + str(len(statTables))
```

The output is

```
size 2 
iteration 0 
length 0
size 2 
iteration 1 
length 0
```

so there are just no pivot tables in the outputDoc at runtime.

Prior to this I tried a mixed approach of spss and SpssClient, I'm somewhat sure I got it from the documentation, however in other places it seems to say don't mix the two modules. The problem with that approach was that it sometimes also didn't execute in the right order and I randomly had some data doubled and some swallowed in the output.

So what is the way to execute a list of syntax commands and get the results with DataCellArray() etc.?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but may help you get where you want: are you aware of OMS facility? It enables you to get the data from the output back into a dataset, ready for analysis. For example you could use OMS to create a file containing the combined results of all the `frequencies` you ran in your loop, and perform more analyses on that.

Comment: Thank you @eli-k, I'm aware of it but not the full extent of its capabilities. I think I'm going to explore this.